# React with webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

how do I change webpack host url? currently my project is running on `localhost:8080`, I want to run my project on `localhost:80/reactApp`, how do I do that?

### configuration of my system

```
 {
      "name": "wp-api",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "curejoy website",
      "main": "http_server.js",
      "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack",
        "start": "webpack-dev-server"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
        "react": "^15.5.4",
        "react-dom": "^15.5.4"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-loader": "^7.0.0",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
        "webpack": "^2.6.1",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5"
      }
    }
```

this my configuration, i am entirely new to this environment, from past two days i am trying to achieve this, but i could not able to do so.

### webpack config file

```
var HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
    template: __dirname + '/reactJs/index.html',
    filename: 'index.html',
    inject: 'body'
});
module.exports={
entry:[__dirname+'/reactJs/index.js',
      'webpack/hot/dev-server',
      'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:80/curejoy'
     ],

 module:{
 loaders:[
  {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    exclude:/node_modules/,
    loader: 'babel-loader'
    }
 ]
 },
 output:{
      filename:'main.js',
      path: __dirname+ '/build'
 },
  plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig]
};
```

this is my webpack config file, here i have defined some with help of google. like entry and outputs. and i tried to change my project url by entry, still nothing happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using webpack it makes your life very easy.

You can use the inbuilt flags provided by webpack.

--host and --port is what you are looking for. Run your server in this format

webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80

Hope that helps!